# Why do floating copies of highlighted text appear (and sometimes get stuck)?

Tags: 20.04

Linux novice here. Enjoying learning to use the terminal to get things done.  However, as the question says, in almost every application on Ubuntu, I seem unable to select text without a floating version of it appearing and following my mouse around the screen.

Sometimes the floating version won't disappear even after unselecting the text. The only thing that appears to remove it are lots of random clicking.

What's going on here, and how do I stop it from happening?

[image: Screenshot of Floating Text Getting Stuck]

Comment: Wow, that's weird. It looks like a helper software is producing it, for some purpose. Almost like some sort of accessibility-helper program. Or maybe some clipboard assistant? Anyways — have you tried to press the `escape` key? Would that get rid of it? (Of course, the long-term solution would be to switch off this feature, but I don't know where even to start looking...)

Comment: What is your exact Ubuntu version? Update: I now see the tag, **20.04**; But is it stock Ubuntu, or some distribution variant?

Comment: Just the regular Ubuntu, I believe. I'm a complete beginner to all this, so I just went for the most mainstream. And yes, pressing Escape sometimes helps, but not always.